# FO to RTF coversion adds unnecessary '\cell' after List block embedded inside table

Tags: apache, apache-fop

I am facing issue with FO to RTF conversion

Below is part of my sample FO

```
.......
<fo:table>
<fo:table-body role="html:tbody">
<fo:table-row role="html:tr">
<fo:table-cell role="html:td">
<fo:block>
<fo:list-block list-style-type="disc" role="html:ul">
<fo:list-item role="html:li">
<fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
<fo:block><fo:inline >•</fo:inline></fo:block>
</fo:list-item-label>
<fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
<fo:block>test data</fo:block>
</fo:list-item-body>
</fo:list-item>
...(similarly many list items)..
</fo:list-block>
..(some more fo:block div data)..
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
.........
```

here i have list item inside one of the table cell followed by some blocks of div data and then i have **< / fo:table-cell>** which is the end of the cell

But while converting this FO to RTF using Apache FOP 1.1, I see that in RTF I have a '\cell' just after the **< / fo:list-block>** so RTF is treating it as end of the cell. so whatever the data I have after  **< / fo:list-block>** and before **< / fo:table-cell>** is not visible in the RTF document.

After some more investigation I found that RTF is pushing all the data which is immediately after the **< / fo:list-block>** and before **< / fo:table-cell>** towards the right side, but due to limited area in RTF document I am unable to see those details

Has anyone faced this kind of issue?, 
any kind of help will be appreciated.

logged Jira issue for the same here
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2624

Comment: Just a guess - give fop 2.1 a try.

Comment: I tested with 2.1 as well.
Apparently this issue persist in 2.1 as well.

Comment: Refer this link 
I have attached FO and RTF  documents here
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2624

Comment: I had seen the open jira issue. You did what you can to address it, but unless you want to dive into fop sources and fix it yourself I think we have to wait for the experts to do so...